# Can anyone get the sync to work on the jumpnote running under a google android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-c2dm

I managed to sign in with my google account (using the Google API AVD), but any notes that I write does not sync to the jumpnote.appspot.com, and vice versa. I notice in the account settings, it says "sync is OFF". I click on menu and the "sync now" button, the sync icon shows up momentarily on top but nothing happened after that. The notes I wrote on the phone do not get reflected on the server. Did anyone manage to get the jumpnote sample to sync successfully via C2DM? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently had this same problem.

To fix it, I followed these steps:

1. From JumpNote's main page, press the device's Menu button and choose Account settings
2. Make sure Auto-sync is turned on here
3. On this page, under Manage Accounts your Google account will be listed. Click on it to go to the Data & synchronization page for the account
4. On the Data & synchronization page for your Google account make sure 'SyncJumpNote' is turned on. This page will also a list of all other components that are synced for this account, like Contacts, Gmail, Calendar and Docs.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same thing.
The logCat showed an exception :authToken was null.

I ran the app in debug mode, and somehow when starting, it asked me for approval of permission to the google app engine. Once granted, problem solved.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue at first, it works fine, you need to setup your google account in the accounts setting in order for C2DM to work.

Do you have a google account logged in to the Emulator?

Comment: thanks for the response. Yes, I have a google account set up already. The "sync is OFF" is next to the google account that has been set up. And I have tested the emulator, gmail and gtalk works fine. Anything else that may have gone wrong?

Comment: Nope, I am running the Google APIs (API 8), not the Android 2.2. With the Android 2.2 the add account screen would not even show up.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the debugger for SyncAdapter.onPerformSync and it is never called...nor any of the functions of SyncAdapter for that matter...dont know if this fact helps...

Comment: Im sorry, I have no idea what might be happening.

Comment: How does the sync work? If you add any notes in the android phone, does the notes show up in the jumpnote.appspot.com?